# How to turn an encoded link such as "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwhatever" into "http://example.com/whatever" in python?

Tags: python, html

I always found links in html source stored in such format, the question is how do I change such links back to what it's normally like?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [urllib.unquote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#utility-functions)

Comment: @Shane: If this is the answer you are looking for. Do accept the answer too.

Comment: @pyfunc: I was going to accept this answer the moment I saw it, but I was not allowed to... So had to return later to accept this answer...

Answer (score 0):

urllib.unquote() on its own may still cause problems by throwing the exception:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position n: ordinal not in range(128)

In that case try:
print urllib.unquote("Ober%C3%B6sterreich.txt").decode("utf8")